# To Create Sub Folders using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code I want to create 2 subfolders in asp.net. I've tried the following code, but it is not creating sub folder. Please help me to do this.

```
string Uploadpath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"];

string sBatchName = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMMyyyyhhmmss");
string[] sFolder = new string[3];
sFolder[0] = "\\Input\\";
sFolder[1] = "\\Data\\";
string strUploadpath = Uploadpath.TrimEnd("\\".ToCharArray()) + "\\" + sBatchName + "\\";

DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(strUploadpath);
if (!dInfo.Exists)
{
    dInfo.Create();
}
for (int i = 0; i < sFolder.Length; i++)
{
    DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(strUploadpath + sFolder[i]);
    if (!dInfo.Exists)
    {
        dInfo.Create();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < sFolder.Length; i++)
{
    DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(strUploadpath + sFolder[i]);
    if (!info .Exists)
    {
        info.Create();
    }
}
```

you should use `info` object instead of `dInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `SubDirectory` by using

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

Where `path` is the path to the `current directory`